# Django Form Update with Queryset

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a model with field ManyToMany, like code bellow :

```
#MODEL
class Car(models.Model):
     description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
     is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=True, blank=True)

class Rental(models.Model):
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    car = models.ManyToManyField(Car)
```

And forms.py code :

```
class RentalUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Rental
         fields = ['car']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.helper = FormHelper()
         self.fields['car'].queryset=Car.objects.filter(is_available=True).all()
```

My question is; how to display **car** on **RentalUpdateForm** with current values selected also display another car with condition **is_available=True** ?

**EDIT**
Like image bellow, i want display car with selected car, also display list another car with condition **is_available=True**

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific what do you exactly want? since, with your current code in `forms.py`, it should display all cars which is available.

Comment: I already edit my question. The point is, when i update my rental, i want display list all cars with is available also selected car like image on my question.

Comment: @SunderamDubey can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that (depending on the form widget used):

```py
current_cars = self.instance.car.all()
self.fields['car'].initial = [c.pk for c in current_cars]

available_cars = Car.objects.filter(is_available=True).all()
self.fields['car'].choices = [(c.pk, c.description) for c in available_cars]
```